# Android Bottom Sheet with Listview not working

Tags: android, xml, listview, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to use a Bottom Sheet with a ListView inside it, but I'm facing two problem, 1st. the ListView doesn't occupy all the space from the Bottom Sheet, the match-parent isn't working, 2nd. scrolling through the list view doesn't really work, if I try to scroll down it only scrolls a little instead of a normal scroll and if I scroll up, the Bottom Sheet closes instead of scrolling the list first.
[Gif of the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0sYkdWQO6iJSGtTSnhMZnhtNlE/view)

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.abili.agriexport2.MapsActivity" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="Direções"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/closeBottomSheet"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:background="@null"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/mr_ic_close_dark" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listaDirecoes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

try to add

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to your `NestedScrollView`

---

For the other problem, I used this way once:

```
yourLV.setOnScrollListener(new ListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
                if (listIsAtTop(yourLV)) {
                    yourLV.setOnTouchListener(null);
                } else {
                    yourLV.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

And

```
  public static boolean listIsAtTop(ListView listView)   {
        if(listView.getChildCount() == 0) return true;
        return listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
    }
```

Comment: Well that fixed problem nº1, thanks a lot, do you have any idea to fix problem nº2?

Comment: @alb sorry for that, ask it on a separate question and some one will may help you :)